# Ruby print directory flags?

Tags: ruby, permissions, directory, chmod

Is there a way to print the current "chmod flags" for a given `Dir` in Ruby?

I'm not an expert on permissions so forgive the terminology, but I'd like to get all possible information about a directory (is it read-only, what are the permissions, etc etc).

Edit: I need this to work in Ruby 1.8.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html#method-c-world_readable-3F

```
sprintf("%o", File.world_readable?("/"))
```

[Ruby 1.8.6 solution](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.6/File/Stat.html#method-i-mode):

```
sprintf("%o", File.stat("/").mode) #40755
```

Comment: @TonyR See my edits.  It will start with a 4 because it is a directory.

Comment: Works great, thanks very much =) Although printing the results of File.stat gives 040755 and File.stat.mode gives 16877

Comment: @TonyR You need to use sprintf to return it in octal.

Comment: Figured it was something like that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bit of shell:

```
`stat --format=%a #{Dir.pwd}`.chomp # => 755
```

It's not pure ruby, but I think it gets the job done.

Comment: Good alternative, but I avoid the shell whenever possible. Windows doesn't come with stat